# Keep Base Mouseover color when changing template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, controltemplate

I have a UI with many buttons.

I changed in my XAML the style of the button to make them have corners:

```
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding Border.CornerRadius}" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="2,2,2,2" >
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style
```

However, now when the mouse `isover` it wont change it color to the basic one (the color i want is basic and i couldnt find what color is it, not green/blue or something).

How can i keep this property even that i changed to corners of the buttons?

Thank you.